# Getting pairs of coordinates in the same column? (R)

Tags: r, list, coordinates

I'm playing around with the `concaveman` package.

I'm using this sample code to create a polygon of a concave hull around some test points:

```
library(concaveman)
data(points)
polygons <- concaveman(points)
plot(points)
plot(polygons, add = TRUE)
```

However, the polygon df has all the coordinates crammed into one row like so:

```
polygons
1
list(c(-122.0809, -122.0813, -122.0812, -122.082, -122.0819, -1...
```

I tried using unlist, but this just separates the x/y coordinate pairs to opposite ends of the df from each other:

```
fixpolygon <- data.frame(unlist(polygons))
```

outputs:

```
polygons1  -122.0809
polygons2  -122.0813
polygons3  -122.0812
...
polygons210 37.3736
polygons211 37.3764
polygons22  37.3767
```

How can I make it so that the output is like so:

```
c(-122.0809, 37.3736)
c(-122.0813, 37.3764)
...
```

etc. etc. ?

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting

```
str(polygons)
```

we can see that what you want is already prepared in

```
polygons$polygons[[1]][[1]]
#               V1      V2
#   [1,] -122.0809 37.3736
#   [2,] -122.0813 37.3764
#   [3,] -122.0812 37.3767
#   [4,] -122.0820 37.3772
#   [5,] -122.0819 37.3792
#   [6,] -122.0822 37.3792
#   ...
```

Comment: @hmnoidk, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `sf` package:

```r
library(sf)
st_coordinates(st_as_sf(polygons))
```

```
             X       Y L1 L2
[1,] -122.0809 37.3736  1  1
[2,] -122.0813 37.3764  1  1
[3,] -122.0812 37.3767  1  1
[4,] -122.0820 37.3772  1  1
[5,] -122.0819 37.3792  1  1
[6,] -122.0822 37.3792  1  1
```